# sending variable to controller and getting it back to view using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my first time to use codeigniter to make a web site.
My problem is as follow:

My view file contains:

```
<label class="control-label ">Insert Number of photos : </label>
<?php echo form_open('project_controller/no_of_pics'); ?>
<input name="no_pics" placeholder="Insert a number" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('no_pics'); ?>" >
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Insert' /> 
<?php echo form_close() ?>
<?php  $no_pic=''; ?>
<?php echo $no_pic; ?>
<br><br>`
```

My controller file contains:

```
public function no_of_pics(){

      $this->load->view('control_panel');
      $number=$this->input->post('no_pics');
      $hoho = array('no_pic' =>  $number  );
      $this->load->view('control_panel',$hoho);

 }
```

and I wrote that line the .htaccess file:

```
$route['project_controller/no_of_pics'] = "/project_controller/no_of_pics";
```

my problem is that I can't get the no_pics back to the view, it is supposed to check the number through validation rules in the controller but I want firstly to get the number back to the view file

when I wrote the code above I get the number back but in a plain page of the view file without any styling and in the top the number I inserted in the input form not even where I want to use.

3-01-2015
I think I knew what the problem is, but I still don't know how to fix it . I have an other method in that controller 
    "project_controller" is:

```
 public function project($page = 'home'){ 
    if ( ! file_exists ('application/views/'.$page.'.php')){ 
       show_404();
     } 
 $this->load->view($page);
 }
```

and I wrote in the route.php file:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'project_controller/project/$1';
```

so I think the problem is `"function no_of_pics()"` can not view the page properly when sending a variable to it as `function project()` is responsible for that , so what is the solution now?

Comment: i think i knew what the problem is , but i still don't know how to fix it .
i have an other method in that controller "project_controller" is:
`public function project($page = 'home'){
 
 if ( ! file_exists ('application/views/'.$page.'.php')){
 show_404();
 }
     
  $this->load->view($page);
  
     }`

and i wrote in the route.php file :
`$route['(:any)'] = 'project_controller/project/$1';`

so i think the problem is "function no_of_pics()" can not view the page properly when sending a variable to it as function project() is responsible for that , so what is the solution now ?!!

Comment: Does anyone understand my problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

You must supply the field name via the first parameter of the function. The second (optional) parameter allows you to set a value for the form.[check here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
set_value('no_pics',$no_pic);
```

Comment: i got the same result after applying the second parameter.

Comment: Are you getting the value  on submit in no_of_pics()? Try Print_r($_POST) and check.

Comment: i already got the value on submit in " <?php echo $no_pic; ?> " i see in the url bar : http://localhost/project/project_controller/no_of_pics
and the number i inserted appears on the top of a white page then after 2 seconds it loads the control_panel view page which i sent the varaible to it but without styling ,please revise my question again i edited it to add more details , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line from view file

```
<?php  $no_pic=''; ?>
```

It reset the variable that passes from the controller.

Comment: but if i remove this line an error message will appear saying undefined variable no_pic !! so i write this line then :
<?php echo $no_pic; ?>
to get the value of $no_pic

Answer (score 0):

You can try this technique

```
  $hoho['no_pic'] =$number;
  $this->load->view('control_panel',$hoho);
```

I think then you find it on view page.

Comment: it is the same result whether sending variable to view file by array or an object .

Comment: i really need help , read my edited question again please for more added details